# django post redirects to it's own page

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I have a form which is displaying table with data and two select dropdown whit who you can choose date/year to display data, so I'm returning `context` for table and with `get_initial` I'm populating dropdowns to use current date and time.

My question is how to make `POST` request redirects to it's own page with `GET`, the idea is to set values in some query parameters in the url like `?month=1&year=2016`, but I don't know where to start, can someone help me understand this, thanks.

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from django.utils import timezone

from .models import Rate
from statistics.forms import StatisticsForm
from statistics.services import StatisticsCalculation


class StatisticsView(FormView):
    template_name = "statistics/invoice_statistics.html"
    form_class = StatisticsForm

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(StatisticsView, self).get_initial()
        initial["month_choice"] = timezone.now().month
        initial["invoice_year"] = timezone.now().year
        return initial

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(StatisticsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        default_currency = Rate.EUR
        currency_usd = Rate.USD
        currency_gbp = Rate.GBP

        context["can_view"] = self.request.user.is_superuser
        context["currency"] = default_currency
        context["currency_usd"] = currency_usd
        context["currency_gbr"] = currency_gbp
        context["statistic"] = StatisticsCalculation.\
            statistic_calculation(supplier_default_currency)
        context["statistic_usd"] = StatisticsCalculation. \
            calculation(supplier_default_currency_usd)
        context["statistic_gbp"] = StatisticsCalculation. \
            statistic_calculation(supplier_default_currency_gbp)
        return context
```

`url` for form:

```
url(r'^statistic/$', login_required(views.StatisticsView.as_view()), name='statistics')
```

template:

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
 <div class="" id="">
   <label for="{{ form.month.month_choice }}"></label>
      {{ form.month_choice }}
 </div>
 <br>
 <div class="" id="">
   <label for="{{ form.year.invoice_year }}"></label>
      {{ form.invoice_year }}
 </div>
 <br>
    # rest of the html
```

Answer (score 0):

Posts will post to where you set them in the HTML form.

Setting the form element like so will send both gets and posts to your view assuming you have urls.py set correctly.

```
<form method='post' action =''>
```

Your url_patterns should include a line something like:

```
url(r'the-url-you want-to-use', StatisticsView.as_view(), name='name_for_reverse_function')
```

Comment: so the `url` is the trick here, it's a simple `url`, so can you explain me how to set my `url`, let me update my question.

Comment: It looks correct, what views are your urls being directed to?

Comment: exactly what I'm getting, the thing is, form is redirecting when I want to browse data, and I don't want that, I want him to stay on that page and show me more data - what do you mean I'm using `FormView`, it's in my question, I have a simple form with two fields for month and year

Comment: Get request goes to that view or gets redirected? Post request goes to that view or gets redirected? You haven't set sucess_url on your view? What does your form template look like?

Comment: @wobbily_cat, updated my question with part of the html

Comment: I need to validate this form properly, I'm not doing that, so (facepalm)